# Unable to access kibana web UI and Elasticsearch running in docker container from host machine

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I build a docker image from dockerfile with ubuntu as the base. 
I manually install elasticsearch kibana airflow in it. The ip of my container is **172.17.0.2**. I am able to access the Airflow's Web UI from the host machine at 172.17.0.2:8080 . However cannot access Kibana or elasticsearch at 172.17.0.2:5601 and 172.17.0.2:9200 respectively.

The following is the excerpt from my dockerfile for installing elasticsearch

```
RUN wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/6.x/apt stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-6.x.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install elasticsearch
```

Please Advice,
Thanks!

Comment: Show your docker run command please.

Comment: docker run -it ec45652e2ca4 /bin/bash
the image  **ec45652e2ca4** contains Kibana and Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I don't know how you can visit `172.17.0.2:8080`. But the common way should be publishing your ports, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports).

For your situation it could be something like:

```
docker run -it -p 5601:5601 -p 8080:8080 -p 9200:9200 your_image
```

Then, use `your_host_ip:5601`, `your_host_ip:8080` etc (Not container ip) to visit the container service.

Comment: I tried 
`docker run -it -p 5601:5601 -p 8080:8080 -p 9200:9200 ec45652e2ca4 /bin/bash`
still not able to access Kibana  127.0.0.1:5601

I also tried this:
`docker run -it -p 192.168.1.107:9200:9200 -p 192.168.1.107:5601:5601 ec45652e2ca4 /bin/bash`
this didn't work either

Comment: how about 172.17.0.2:5601? i.e your_container_ip:5601

Comment: @yasirkhatri __1:__ You should first in container use `netstat -oanltp | grep 5601`, `netstat -oanltp | grep 9200` to confirm the service really start or not? __2:__ If step 1  not shown any process, then means this not related to network, it means your service not start; if port in container all open, then you need to check it in host, note: `192.168.107:9200` should be visited from host not container, also, use try `netstat -oanltp | grep 9200` on host to see if port mapping sucessful or not on host. __3:__ If all above ok, then it may related to iptables etc.

Comment: You should also delete `/bin/bash` from the command: it will start a shell _instead of_ the code in the image.

Comment: Yeah, updated, maybe OP's service not start, so @yasirkhatri Could you really confirm your service start with netstat or ps -ef? I deleted the /bin/bash, but, do you properly define all service in entrypoint or cmd as I see you have `elasticsearch kibana airflow` so many things want to start. Or you just start them one by one in `/bin/bash`?

Comment: in the interactive session with the container i write `service elasticsearch start` and `service kibana start`
the status of both the services is *running.
sorry for the delay in response.

Answer (score 0):

If you've successfully installed kibana and docker inside your docker image build-ed  container then you've to **EXPOSE** the ports for **kibana default port 5601** and **elasticsearch default port 9200** before accessing it from the local host. You can do it by two different ways. For example: at the dockerfile `EXPOSE 5601 9200 8080` or at the time when running the container. So If you want access the Kibana UI or Elasticsearch that reside inside your Airflow container then you can remove the existing container and re-run it with port expose. Let's say-

**At [container running](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports) time,**

```
docker run -it --name webui_kibana_elasticsearch -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 -p 8080:8080 ec45652e2ca4 /bin/bash
```

**At [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) building time,**

```
EXPOSE 8080 5601 9200
```

Alternatively If you want to use Kibana and Elasticsearch in separate docker container then this articale will help you for sure.

**See here**

https://docs.swiftybeaver.com/article/33-install-elasticsearch-kibana-via-docker 
and

https://gist.github.com/sany2k8/347690434b282369890057d094218c7f

Comment: I tried `docker run -it --name webui_kibana_elasticsearch -p 5601:5601 -p 9200:9200 -p 8080:8080 ec45652e2ca4 /bin/bash`
Only airflow is accessible.